# Git: Insert existing commits from one branch into another branch's history

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

I want to insert several commits from one branch into the history of another, so that:

```
A - B - F - G - H - I - J  (branch working)
    \
      C - D - E            (old branch)
```

becomes...

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I - J (continue with branch working)
```

Anything I've tried so far has resulted in multiple conflicts preventing me from continuing, but I don't care about them as long as the state of the subsequent commits is the same. Is the problem that commit F "doesn't know" how to become the child of commit E?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You literally can't do *that*, because that would involve changing some existing commit.  In this case, existing commit `F` stores `B`'s hash ID as its parent.  No existing commit can ever be changed: commits are entirely read-only (in fact, all of Git's internal objects are read-only).

I assume you want to pretend that `F` stores `E`'s hash ID as its parent instead, without changing the snapshot associated with any of the existing commits.  You *can* do *this*, and you can do a number of similar things.  Before we look at those, though, let's look at `git rebase`.

The problem with using `git rebase` here is that rebase functions by *copying* commits (which is all well and good so far), with each copy made as if<sup>1</sup> by using `git cherry-pick` (which is where things start to go wrong).  To cherry-pick one single commit, Git will:

- Compare the commit's snapshot vs the commit's parent's snapshot, e.g., `J` vs `I`, or `F` vs `B`.  You can do this yourself by running `git diff <hash1> <hash2>`, or more simply by `git show <hash2>`.
- Merge the diff shown here with the diff from the parent (the `<hash1>` above) to the current or `HEAD` commit, and use the merge result to make a new commit.
- Copy the original commit's message to the new commit.

The new commit, as always, goes onto the current branch, making the branch one commit longer and changing the `HEAD` commit to name the new commit.

The merge step, plus the fact that Git is converting snapshots (commits) to changesets (diffs), mean that the final cherry-picked result can be a very different snapshot, as compared to the original.  This all depends on how different `<hash1>` is from whatever is `HEAD` when you start the process.

The `git rebase` command essentially automates the process of cherry-picking a whole series of commits at once.  At the end of all the copying, `git rebase` forces the branch label to point to the final copied commit.  This would allow you to copy `F` to a new `F'` whose parent is `E`, then copy `G` to a new `G'` whose parent is `F'`, and so on:

```
A--B--F--G--H--I--J   <-- (original)
    \
     C--D--E   <-- (target of rebase)
            \
             F'-G'-H'-I'-J'   <-- branch
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Sometimes `git rebase` literally runs `git cherry-pick`, and sometimes it uses a method that should usually produce the same result, but in some odd corner cases, doesn't.

---

Now, suppose that instead of all this, we make a Git object that Git can "look aside" to, whenever it's about to use `F`.  This replacement-for-`F` goes into the graph like this:

```
A--B--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch
    \
     C--D--E   <-- some_name
            \
             Frepl   <-- refs/replace/<hash>
```

We copy the commit message for `F` to that for `Frepl`, and copy most of the other fields as well, including the internal Git hash ID for the tree object for the commit.  But instead of pointing to commit `B`, commit `Frepl` points to commit `E`.

Now we just need Git to "turn its eyes" from `F` to `Frepl` every time it's about to work with commit `F` for any reason.  And there is a way to do that: we give `Frepl` a special name, `refs/replace/big-ugly-hash-id`, where *`big-ugly-hash-id`* is the actual hash ID of commit `F`.

The Git command that makes the replacement is `git replace`.  The looking-aside is automatic: Git always does it, unless we run `git --no-replace-objects`.  This is all done *without* changing any *existing* Git object, so it's just adding to the repository.

The biggest drawback to a replacement object is that `git clone` by default *does not* copy the replacement objects (it does not fetch them, nor their names).  This means that the clone does not have the replacement in view, and never looks aside to it.  You can explicitly add the replacements to your fetch refspecs to get them, but it's a bit of a pain.  The `git push` operations don't transfer them by default either.

The big advantage is that they do not require everyone to stop using the original commits in favor of new-and-improved commits.  If you *can* get everyone to switch over, though, you can use `git rebase` to copy many commits and move the branch label.  Or, you can use `git replace` initially to make the replacement object, then run `git filter-branch` with no filters, but telling it to filter the branch(es) on which the replacement(s) occur.

What `git filter-branch` does is to copy *every* commit (on the branch or branches it's told to filter).  It—at least logically; there's a lot of optimization—extracts each commit, working from oldest commits to newest, to a temporary directory, applies every filter in some sequence, then makes a new commit using whatever the filters did.  If the new commit is bit-for-bit identical to the original, the two commits are actually just one commit, otherwise the copy is a new and different commit.  The default parent(s) for each new copy are the commits made in the earlier copy of the parent(s) (though there is a `--parent-filter` to let you change that!).  It does all of this with the replacement lookaside gimmick happening,<sup>2</sup> so when Git goes to copy `F`, it actually copies `Frepl` instead, and then follows `Frepl` back to `E`.  If we have this filter the name `branch`, the result is that Git copies `A`, then `B`, then `C`, then `D`, then `E`, then `Frepl`, then `G`, then `H`, then `I`, and then `J`, giving:

```
A--B--F--G--H--I--J   <-- refs/original/refs/heads/branch
    \
     C--D--E   <-- some_name
            \
             Frepl   <-- refs/replace/<hash>
                \
                 G'-H'-I'-J'   <-- branch
```

Note that `branch` points to commit `J'`, whose parent is `I'` but whose tree (snapshot) is the same as that of `J`.  Commit `I'` points back to `H'`, which points back to `G'`, which points back to `Frepl` (the copy we made back when we ran `git replace`: it stayed unchanged during the filtering).  This points back to `E` (which is its own unchanged copy), which points back to `D`, and so on back to `A`.

The final effect, then, if we toss out all the `refs/original/` names like `refs/original/refs/heads/branch`, is to "cement in place" any replacement commits.  We can then delete the `refs/replace/` name for `Frepl` and it looks as if we only ever had commits `A-B-C-D-E-Frepl-G'-H'-I'-J'` in the repository.  The *hash IDs* of many commits have changed, so this repository is no longer compatible with the original repository; but if we start from the name `branch`, we see only the shiny new copied commits in all the right places.

---

<sup>2</sup>Of course, if you run `git --no-replace-objects filter-branch`, that disables the replacement lookaside.  There's probably never any reason to do this.